# import pandas in processing 3.3

Tags: python, csv, pandas, processing

pandas is an open source, BSD-licensed library providing high-performance, easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools for the Python programming.

and want to use it in my processing and load huge CSV file but i dont know how to import it in processing 3.3

thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`the processing tutorial pages`](http://py.processing.org/tutorials/python-jython-java/):

> popular Python libraries like numpy, scipy and scikit-learn will not work in Jython (and, for this reason, will not work in Processing.py).

No numpy means no pandas. Sorry.  Try using the builtin `csv` module instead.